# Encryption and decryption in Nifi using EncryptContent processor , want to read content in attribute

Tags: apache-nifi

I am trying to Encrypt the content using EncryptContent Processor for AES encryption

After encryption am trying to read whole content in an Attribute

after the completion i want to replace whole content with my Attribute which contains Encrypted content

but now the Encrypted content is not the same so am not able to Decrypt it

Processor are like below

EncyrptContent ===> ExtractText(read whole content in an Attribute) ===> ReplaceText(whole content with Attribute containg Encryted content) ====> EncyrptContent( for decryption )

or if there is any other way to just Encrypt the Attribute With AES encryption . base64 encryption i can do but AES128 Encryption is welcomed

Comment: I believe AES produces bytes. You can store into attribute only text. So, before this you have to convert bytes to text and base64 is a good choice. `EncyrptContent->  Base64EncodeContent -> ExtractText`

Answer (score 2):

I think there is a lot to unpack here:

1. It is generally an anti-pattern to move large amounts of data from flowfile content to attributes. Sometimes the content is plain text or JSON and extracting a specific value to an attribute to route or use for enrichment makes sense. But bringing arbitrary content bytes out into attributes has a negative impact on performance because of the way [the multiple repositories are architected](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/nifi-in-depth.html).
2. If you encrypt flowfile content using `EncryptContent`, the cipher text is stored as raw bytes. Attributes are strings, and thus it is very likely (almost guaranteed) there will be data corruption & loss pulling raw bytes from content to an attribute.
3. I don't understand your proposed flow -- encrypting the content, extracting it to an attribute, then replacing the flowfile content with that attribute is semantically a no-op, but realistically only serves to corrupt the data.
4. Base64 is an encoding scheme, not an encryption algorithm. Converting data to Base64 makes it resilient against data loss in media that only support US-ASCII characters, but it does not protect the data against inspection.
5. If your objective is to encrypt an attribute, you can do so with an `ExecuteScript` processor and custom code to perform the encryption over the attribute value.